# 'LocalLibrary' file

Tags: library, spellcheck, spelling

I'm looking to add a large number of words to my spell checker lexicon. I've been told to go to Library > Spelling > LocalLibrary, but there is no such file in my Spelling folder (or anywhere else on the computer). There is only 'dynamic-counts.dat', 'dynamic-text-tmp.dat', and 'dynamic-text.dat'. I'm on a MacBook Pro, Mojave 10.14.1. Is there another way of adding a batch of words?

Answer (score 1):

It's called LocalDictionary not Library & is just a plain text file, but has no .txt extension.
I also have two others, called en and en_GB. I really don't know what the difference is, but they all contain different custom word lists.

Presumably, if there isn't one there already, you just need to create one.

If you don't want the task of doing that yourself, then right click any word the regular spellcheck doesn't like & 'Learn Spelling' - I'm pretty sure that should create the file & populate it with your first word.

One thing to note, if you're going the DIY route for this - words are in alphabetical order, not just added by date to the next line.

Comment: Oops, you're right, thanks. Even so, there doesn't appear to be a 'LocalDictionary' either, and clicking 'Add to Dictionary' for an unknown word in a Word document doesn't create any new files. The 'dynamic-text' files seem to be filled with words that I changed back from their autosuggestions in Safari. What extension would I have to use to create a LocalLibrary file? Just use a plain text file?

Comment: MS Word will use its own structure, not Apple's. I'm afraid I don't know much about Office at all, so can't help in finding that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try /usr/share/dict/words maybe append your list of words to that file.